# Dash Python multitab app with error:" ID not find in layout....."

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I'm building an application with multiple tabs, but I'm getting the error: "Attempting to connect a callback Input item to component:
"dropdown......."
but no components with that id exist in the layout."
This error is thrown 12 times (once for each callback it seems), even though the first page works and the second one doesn't. When I set suppress_callback_exceptions=True, it still throws those errors, although this time it runs and shows the graphs. What's the issue? Is there a more optimal way? Any suggestions of any kind are welcome.
This mi code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from graficos_z import diagrama_CM, sp_str
from Historias_group import evol_circ, heatmap_history

# Inicializar la aplicación Dash
app = dash.Dash( __name__,suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

# Layout first page
page_1_layout = html.Div([
    # First Row
    html.H1("General property", style={'text-align': 'center'}),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown_tipo_galaxia', 
                 options=[{'label': 'Lenticulares', 'value': 'Galnow.dat'},
                          {'label': 'Spiral', 'value': 'Galnow-ESP.dat'}],
                 value='Galnow.dat'),  

    dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown_central_satelite', 
                 options=[{'label': 'Centrales', 'value': 0},
                          {'label': 'Satélites', 'value': 1}],
                 value=0), 

    dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown_id_galaxia', 
                 value=None), 
    
   
    dcc.Graph(id='grafico_propiedades_generales'),

    # Second row
    html.H1("Spiral arms", style={'text-align': 'center'}),
    dcc.Graph(id='grafico_brazos_espirales'),
    
], style={'height': '2000px'}) 

#layout second page

page_2_layout = html.Div([
    # first row
    html.H1("Evolucion de caracteristicas", style={'text-align': 'center'}),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown_tipo',
                 options=[{'label': 'Spiral', 'value': 'espiral'},
                          {'label': 'Lenticular', 'value': 'lenticular'}],
                 value='lenticular'),
    
    dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown_centralidad',
                 options=[{'label': 'Central', 'value': 0},
                          {'label': 'Satélite', 'value': 1}],
                 value=0),  

    dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown_rango_masa',
                 options=[{'label': 'Alta Masa', 'value': 'HighMass'},
                          {'label': 'Media Masa', 'value': 'MediumMass'},
                          {'label': 'Baja Masa', 'value': 'LowMass'}],
                 value='MediumMass'),

    dcc.Graph(id='circu_y_coldgas'),

    
    # Second row
    html.H1("Historias de color", style={'text-align': 'center'}),
    dcc.Graph(id='historia_color_cen'),
    dcc.Graph(id='historia_color_sat')
], style={'height': '2000px'})


#  general Layout
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Tabs(id='tabs', value='tab-1', children=[
        dcc.Tab(label='General property', value='tab-1'),
        dcc.Tab(label='Evolucion', value='tab-2'),
    ]),
    html.Div(id='tabs-content')
])

# Callback para actualizar el contenido de las pestañas
@app.callback(Output('tabs-content', 'children'),
              [Input('tabs', 'value')])

def render_content(tab):
    if tab == 'tab-1':
        return page_1_layout
    elif tab == 'tab-2':
        return page_2_layout

# Callback para actualizar las opciones del dropdown de ID de galaxia
@app.callback(
    Output('dropdown_id_galaxia', 'options'),
    [Input('dropdown_tipo_galaxia', 'value'),
     Input('dropdown_central_satelite', 'value'),
     Input('dropdown_tipo_galaxia', 'value')]  
)

def update_id_dropdown(tipo_galaxia, central_satelite, tipo_galaxia_previo):
 
    # Verificar si el tipo de galaxia ha cambiado

    if tipo_galaxia != tipo_galaxia_previo:
        # dropdown id_galaxia en None
        return []
    
    # Leer los datos relevantes según las selecciones de los dropdown
    df = pd.read_csv(tipo_galaxia, delim_whitespace=True)
    dff = df[df['central?'] == central_satelite]
    
    options = [{'label': str(galaxia_id), 'value': galaxia_id} for galaxia_id in dff['ids']]
    
    return options

# Callback update graphs first tab 
@app.callback(
    [Output('grafico_propiedades_generales', 'figure'),
     Output('grafico_brazos_espirales', 'figure')],
    [Input('dropdown_tipo_galaxia', 'value'),
     Input('dropdown_central_satelite', 'value'),
     Input('dropdown_id_galaxia', 'value')]
)
def update_graphs_1(tipo_galaxia, central_satelite, id_galaxia):
    
    # Call functions to make graphs

    figure_1 = diagrama_CM(tipo_galaxia, central_satelite) 
    figure_2 = sp_str(tipo_galaxia, central_satelite)
    
    path=tipo_galaxia
    
    # Highlight a point in the graph

    if id_galaxia:
        
        df = pd.read_csv(path, delim_whitespace=True)  

        dff = df[df['ids'] == id_galaxia]
        
        if not dff.empty:

            sSFR = np.log10(dff['SFR'] / dff['masa-estelar'])
            # reemplazo los infinitos con un valor ya que -inf corresponde a SFR = 0
            sSFR = sSFR.replace(-np.inf, -13)

            
            x_column = [dff['mag_r'].iloc[0], dff['masa-estelar'].iloc[0]]
            y_column = [dff['mag_g'].iloc[0]-dff['mag_r'].iloc[0],sSFR.iloc[0]]

            figure_1.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                x=[x_column[0]],
                y=[y_column[0]],
                mode='markers',
                marker=dict(color='red', symbol='diamond', size=30, 
                line=dict(color='black', width=2)),
               showlegend=False,  
            ), row=1, col=2)


            figure_1.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                x=np.log10([x_column[1]]),
                y=[y_column[1]],
                customdata=dff['ids'],
                mode='markers',
                marker=dict(color='red', symbol='diamond', size=30,  # Tamaño del punto aumentado
            line=dict(color='black', width=2)),              
                showlegend=False,  
            ), row=1, col=2)

    return figure_1, figure_2


# update graphs belong to second tab

@app.callback(
    [Output('circu_y_coldgas', 'figure'),
     Output('historia_color_cen', 'figure'),
     Output('historia_color_sat', 'figure')],
    [Input('dropdown_rango_masa', 'value'),
    Input('dropdown_centralidad', 'value'),
    Input('dropdown_tipo', 'value')]
)

def update_graphs_2(rango_masa,centralidad,tipo_galaxia):
    
    # Functions to make graps

    figure_1 =  evol_circ(tipo_galaxia,rango_masa,centralidad)
    
    figure_2 = heatmap_history(rango_masa,tipo_galaxia,0)
    figure_3 = heatmap_history(rango_masa,tipo_galaxia,1)
    
    return figure_1, figure_2,figure_3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[All errors are like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxZXO.jpg)